# Check if a string starts with any letter between 'A' and 'G' in django template

Tags: python, django

How can I check if a string starts with 'A' or 'B' or 'C'.... or 'G' in django template.

I've this method presently. Can it be done in a better way?

```
{% if val|slice:":1" == 'A' or val|slice:":1" == 'B' or val|slice:":1" == 'C'.... or val|slice:":1" == 'G' %}
```

Comment: If you're going to reuse this, you might want to write a template tag for it (and give it a good name so it would make sense - why A B C or G?).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Strings are treated like sequences in Python so you can check membership like so:

```
{% if val|first in 'ABCG' %}
    # Do stuff
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That's not valid django template syntax. You have to do what OP did: `{% if val|slice:":1" in "ABCG" %}`. Edit: or even better `{% val|first in 'ABCG' %}.`

Comment: My bad, I'm used to Jinja2. Edited the post. Thanks for that